# Image with irregular borders to display as one concat image in java

Tags: java, image, swing

[image: Map]

See the above map, actually I will have following images saved:

1. D-Yellow.png

   D-Red.png

   D-Blue.png

   D-Green.png

   A-Yellow.png

   A-Red.png

   A-Blue.png

   A-Green.png

and so on.

That is B-Blue.png has the area marked `B`in the above map, filled with blue color
In my ***Java*** program, I will use all the images in a array.

First initially screen will have the map above, the user can change the color by inputting the respective town name(i.e. A, B, C or D) and required color. Then I should replace that particular image with the prompted image.

---

Example
The user tells to change A to blue color, then following should appear:
[image]

## Please help me also how to display these images which have irregular borders as one image

Comment: Make all images rectangular (with "regular borders"), paint only the region of interest, and make the rest of image transparent. Then merge them, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318020/merging-two-images).

Comment: @linski Ok, but I have last doubt, How to make images transparent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare images with transparency, and then use compositing as explained here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html

Basically compositing is achieved by setting a composite attribute to the `Graphics2D` object.

Sample code available here: [Blending images in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515761/blending-images-in-java)

Comment: Ok, but I have last doubt, How to make images transparent

Comment: If you are using GIMP check here:http://docs.gimp.org/nl/gimp-using-web-transparency.html